# require_once - does it load the whole script?

Tags: php, require-once

Just wondering if require_once (or any of the include type functions) loads the entire external script when you call it, or just the functions from that script as you call them from the script you are using require_once in?

Comment: PHP has to read the whole file to know what it contains. It loads the whole script.

Comment: PHP is interpreted - it _has to_ load the whole file to evaluate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It loads the entire script. The only difference between `require` and `require_once` is that if you call `require_once` multiple times with the same script argument, the repetitions will be ignored.

A script loaded with `require` or `include` can have other things besides function definitions, and they need to be executed immediately when the file is loaded.

Comment: Thanks guys - that makes a difference to how I was going to do things.